# Saving 2 versions of an entity at the same time

Tags: jpa, entity

I'm currently trying to implement a CRUD-Application für Orders/Articles in JSF/Primefaces.

Whenever I create a new version of an article I want to merge the old entity with a different status and save the new entity populated by form input with a new ID.

This is the relationship between Article and OrderLine:
[image]

The Article Entity has the following field:

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "fkArticleID")
@XmlTransient
private Collection<OrderLine> orderLineCollection;
```

This is the method that updates/saves the new Entity:

```
public void edit(Article article) throws OptimisticLockException {


        /* PK des Auftrags/der Auftragsposition speichern um die Suche zu vereinfachen */
        int articleID = article.getArticleID();

        /**
         *
         * Falls sich article im Zustand "detached" befindet, werden in
         * attachedArticle die aktuellen Daten aus der DB geladen.
         *
         * Falls sich orderLine im Zustand "managed" befindet, werden in
         * attachedOrderLine die Daten aus dem PersistenceContext geladen. Dies
         * ist notwendig, da nur Datensätze für Entities gesperrt werden können
         * die sich im Zustand "managed" befinden.
         *
         */
        Article attachedArticle = em.find(Article.class, articleID, LockModeType.OPTIMISTIC);

        /* Prüfen ob der Artikel noch in der Datenbank vorhanden ist */
        if (attachedArticle != null) {
            /*  Laden des aktuellsten Datensatzes aus der Datenbank */
            Article latestVersionArticle = findLatestVersion(articleID);
            /*  Anhand der Version wird geprüft ob die bearbeiteten Daten noch konsistent mit dem Zustand der Datenbank sind */
            if (latestVersionArticle.getVersion() == article.getVersion()) {
                /**
                 * Schreibt den bearbeiteten Artikel zurück in die Datenbank,
                 * Versionsnummer wird am Ende der Transaktion automatisch
                 * inkrementiert (optimistische Sperre)
                 */
                latestVersionArticle.setArticleStatus(ArticleStatus.GESPERRT);
                em.merge(latestVersionArticle);

                /**
                 * Erstellt einen neuen Artikel mit den eingegebenen Daten und
                 * dem Status Freigegeben.
                 */
                article.setArticleStatus(ArticleStatus.FREIGEGEBEN);
                article.setOrderLineCollection(null);
                em.persist(article);

            } else {
                /* OptimisticLockException werfen falls die Daten des Auftrags nicht mehr konsistent sind */

                throw new OptimisticLockException(article);
            }

        } else {
            throw new OptimisticLockException(article);
        }

    }
```

Everything seems to work fine at first.. however the newer Version of the article seems to automatically create another OrderLine which shows up in the existing Order.. so whenever I "update" an article, while the newer version is created, it is also creating another OrderLine.. I suspect the fault lies with the @OneToMany field in the Article-Entity.. I'm trying to set the orderLineCollection to null before persisting but it doesnt seem to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to remove cascading on the orderLineCollection.
If you persist an article, you'll always get duplicates of the existing orderLines.

Please also consider to remove the bidirectional relationship between Article and OrderLine. Usually you only need a unidirectional relationship from OrderLine to Article. If you need all OrderLines for an article, you can use a NamedQuery.

Comment: thank you! removing the relationship solved the problem 